# Expanding an encrypted xfs volume

Tags: partitioning, luks, aws, xfs

I am working on expanding a currently attached volume to one of my Ubuntu Amazon AWS servers, but I am having some problems.  I already created a new volume from a snapshot, then attached the newly created volume to the EC2 instance.  I prepare the volume for use by the following commands:

```
sudo vgchange -a y
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/mapper/vgdata2-lvdata cryptmnt
```

This volume was originally 600GB and is now 700GB.  After mounting the volume with

```
sudo mount /dev/mapper/cryptmnt /mnt/ebs1
```

I try to expand the volume using

```
sudo xfs_growfs -d /mnt/ebs1/
```

Which results in this output

```
meta-data=/dev/mapper/cryptmnt   isize=256    agcount=4, agsize=39321280 blks
         =                       sectsz=512   attr=2
data     =                       bsize=4096   blocks=157285119, imaxpct=25
         =                       sunit=0      swidth=0 blks
naming   =version 2              bsize=4096   ascii-ci=0
log      =internal               bsize=4096   blocks=76799, version=2
         =                       sectsz=512   sunit=0 blks, lazy-count=1
realtime =none                   extsz=4096   blocks=0, rtextents=0
data size unchanged, skipping
```

I have no idea if I'm doing something wrong or if there are steps that I am missing.  Running `df -h` after this results in the following output

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1             7.9G  4.8G  2.7G  65% /
none                  827M  124K  827M   1% /dev
none                  833M     0  833M   0% /dev/shm
none                  833M   52K  833M   1% /var/run
none                  833M     0  833M   0% /var/lock
/dev/mapper/cryptmnt  600G  598G  2.3G 100% /mnt/ebs1
```

Which shows that the volume was not resized.

Answer (score 3):

When resizing a volume, you need to resize all the layers, starting from the bottom up.

In this case you have 6 layers:

- EC2 volume
- LVM physical volume
- LVM volume group *(automatic upon resizing the physical volume)*
- LVM logical volume
- LUKS volume
- XFS filesystem

*In this case "bottom" means the first one*

#### Resize the LVM physical volume:

```
pvresize /dev/xvdH
```

*(replace with the actual device path)*

#### Resize the logical volume

```
lvresize -l +100%FREE vgdata2-lvdata
```

*(adjust to how much space you want the volume to use if not 100%)*

#### Resize the luks volume

```
cryptsetup resize /dev/mapper/cryptmnt
```

#### Resize the filesystem

```
xfs_growfs /mnt/ebs1
```

Comment: As far as I know, `cryptsetup resize` is for old, non-LUKS volumes only. For LUKS you don't have to do anything.

Comment: @bseibold last time I did my luks volume (couple months ago) I had to do it.

Comment: Well ok, I always close the volume during resize, so it's not necessary. If you have it opened, you might need it.

Comment: There is a detailed description avaiable here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeEncryptedPartitions

Comment: @bseibold Ah yes, I always resize online. So that would probably be it.